# Append numbers to vectors with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, scipy

I want to store multiple forces at certain positions with NumPy.

I need a vector with the positions `positions` and a vector with the forces `forces` at the certain positions. I am prompting the user to input these positions and forces with `input("Please input position: ")` and `input("Please input force: ")`.

How can I append these inputted values to two separate vectors with NumPy? I've tried

```
import numpy as np

# empty as default
positions = None
forces = None

# append
np.append(positions, int(input("Please input position: ")))
np.append(forces, int(input("Please input position: ")))

# print positions and forces
print(positions)
print(forces)
```

but the variables `positions` and `forces` stay empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems here.

First, `None` is not an array, so appending to it doesn't make any sense. (NumPy will actually let you do this, but it does so by treating it as `array([None], dtype=object)`, which is almost certainly not what you want.)

Second, [`append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) doesn't modify its array argument in-place, it returns a new array.<sup>*</sup> As the docs say:

> A copy of *arr* with *values* appended to *axis*. Note that `append` does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled.

Also, you really should set the dtype of the array when you create it; otherwise, you're going to get the default `float64`, and NumPy is going to wastefully convert all your nice integers into floats.

So, to do what you wanted:

```
positions = np.array([], dtype=int)
forces = np.array([], dtype=int)

# append
positions = np.append(positions, int(input("Please input position: ")))
forces = np.append(forces, int(input("Please input position: ")))

# print positions and forces
print(positions)
print(forces)
```

---

Third, NumPy arrays are not meant to be grown one element at a time. This problem isn't causing your error—and for arrays this tiny (size `(1,)`), it won't even have a noticeable effect—but it's a very bad habit to get into. Many other types, like Python's built-in lists, are good for that, but not NumPy arrays.

Usually either you know in advance how many values you're going to have, in which case you can pre-allocate the array. If not, you're usually building it from some kind of iterable that you build dynamically, like a `list`.<sup>**</sup> Here are some examples:

```
# Pre-allocating the array
positions = np.zeros((1,), dtype=int)
positions[0] = int(input("Please input position: "))

# Building the array from a dynamically-built list
positions = []
positions.append(int(input("Please input position: ")))
positions = np.array(positions, dtype=int)

# Building the array all at once from a static list
positions = np.array([int(input("Please input position: "))], dtype=int)
```

---

<sub>* If it *did* try to modify things in-place, the first problem would be even worse, because then you'd be trying to modify the immutable singleton value `None`…</sub>

<sub>** For very large arrays, don't use a `list`, because the cost of building that temporary `list` will be too high. Instead, you often want to create a generator, or some other type of lazy iterator, and use `np.fromiter`.</sub>

Comment: Adding one number at a time to an array is the worst application of `np.append`.  This is a case for list append, not the array approximation.

Comment: @hpaulj: Agreed, but this is what the OP asked for. Do you think the answer needs to be expanded to explain that you should think of arrays as fixed-size preallocated collections rather than treating them as expanding collections like list, and show him the better ways to do what he wanted? (Start with a list of 2 elements instead of empty then fill them, build a list and then convert to array if needed, or just put both expressions into one array constructor.)

Comment: Yes, there's a tension between directly answering a question and encouraging poor practices.  I kind of wish they hadn't added `np.append` because beginners often misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

just like this:

```
positions = np.array(())
positions=np.append(positions, int(input("Please input position: ")))
```